# When ListView has no data, OnScrollListener's onScroll can not be fired?

Tags: android, listview

I need to load more data when user scrolls to near the end of the listview.

When ListView's adapter has no data, OnScrollListener's onScroll can not be fired!
When the ListView's setAdapter be called, the OnScrollListener's onScroll will be called. But when user push the screen and scroll the ListView(which has no data), the OnScrollListener's onScroll has not been call. 
When ListView has at least on row, the OnScrollListener's onScroll will be called if user scroll the listview.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is call `setAdapter` just once, in my `onCreate` method using an `ArrayAdapter`. I pass in a `List` which I maintain a reference to. When I want to add more items, I add them to this list. Then I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.

In this manner, you can add more items to the end of your list when the user gets to the bottom, and not clear your ListView or set a new Adapter.